# Use .env values in Craft 3 plugin settings

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, environmentvariables

I’m writing a plugin and need some of its settings to be pulled from the `.env` file. According to [the docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/environmental-settings.html) the following should work, but the getter isn’t getting called whenever the plugin’s `youtubeApiKey` setting is requested; it just keeps returning `$YOUTUBE_API_KEY`.

When I set the property visibility to `protected` instead of `public`, it *does* call the getter but also reveals the (sensitive) key in he admin settings panel.

```
class Settings extends Model
{
    public $youtubeApiKey = '$YOUTUBE_API_KEY';

    public function getYoutubeApiKey(): string
    {
        return Craft::parseEnv($this->youtubeApiKey);
    }

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'parser' => [
                'class' => EnvAttributeParserBehavior::class,
                'attributes' => ['youtubeApiKey'],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['youtubeApiKey'], 'string'],
            [['youtubeApiKey'], 'default', 'value' => ''],
        ];
    }
}
```

I suppose my understanding of the settings getters is incorrect, but what I’m trying to achieve is for `MyPlugin::getInstance()->getSettings()->youtubeApiKey` to return the actual API key (not `$YOUTUBE_API_KEY`) and for the settings field (below) to display `$YOUTUBE_API_KEY` (not the actual API key).

```
{{ forms.textField({
    'id': 'youtubeApiKey',
    'label': 'YouTube API key',
    'name': 'youtubeApiKey',
    'suggestEnvVars': true,
    'value': settings.youtubeApiKey
}) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try declaring the variable $youtubeApiKey with no value set. Instead of using

```
public $youtubeApiKey = '$YOUTUBE_API_KEY';
```

try using

```
public $youtubeApiKey;
```